# TimerOne and Serial Libraries

Tags: timer, arduino, atmega

I'm working using [TimerOne library](http://playground.arduino.cc/code/timer1), the code is shown below:

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);    
    Serial.println();
    Timer1.initialize(1000000); // set a timer of length 1000000 microseconds
    Timer1.attachInterrupt(timerIsr); // attach the service routine here
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(millis());
}

void timerIsr() {
    Serial.print("FROM Time1: ");
    Serial.println(millis());
}
```

The problem is, after some loops (when millis of loop() returns 930), the arduino stop

I think that the problem is, when the arduino is running the loop, and write in Serial port, the ISR Routine is writing too. How can I solve this problem?

I try change:

```
Serial.print("FROM Time1: ");
Serial.println(millis());
```

by:

```
digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13));
```

And work fine, I think that the Serial library of arduino has some problem when use interrupts, It's possible?

There's any way to block arduino in some block of code, I try use [atomic](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__atomic.html) and didn't work.

I'm using Arduino UNO (ATmega328)

Answer (score 3):

First problem is that your ISR (Interrupt Service Routine), **MUST NOT** perform any IO.
Instead write something, like:

```
int timedone;

setup() {
   // etc.
   timedone = 0;
}

loop() {
   if (timedone == 1)
   {
    Serial.print("FROM Time1: ");
    Serial.println(millis());
   }
}

void timerISR() {timedone = 1;}
```

Instead of what you have:

```
void timerIsr() {
    Serial.print("FROM Time1: ");
    Serial.println(millis());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time to discovery.

Just

```
Serial.flush();
```

:/

Comment: apparently there were two problems: issuing an IO from an ISR and not flushing the serial buffer?  The buffer will flush automatically when it is filled.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why, but when I flushing the serial buffer in ISR and Loop() work fine :D

Comment: try flushing just in loop() and NOT in the ISR.  As a good programming practice an ISR should NOT perform I/O (printf, etc.), eventually your code will be complex enough where you encounter problems with I/O from an ISR.